# How to install angularjs for django

Tags: django, angularjs

I am just learning django (and subsequently python) and need to install angularjs.

I found `pip install django-angular` to install the package but [the page I looked at](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) lists a dependency of AngularJS >= 1.2. I followed the link and found a download for the angular files.

My confusion starts here. What do I do with the files in the zipped download? They need to be on my linux box.

Comment: `django-angular` should provide those for you. What happens when you follow the tutorial?

Comment: Didn't go any further ...since I'm so new to this environment - I've been VS, .Net, C# for 10 years all on Windows - I stopped at the first sign of confusion. I'll let you know if simply installing this will work.

Comment: You can also use angularjs with django without installing anything. Django is for server side scripting and angularjs is for client side scripting. So theorically they are supposed to work independently. The interaction being provided by the HTTP protocol when you call post or get from angular to django.